# Why is there fear of interference between 5G and airline altimeter C-band?

Tags: digital-communications, channel, interference

The C-band frequency range to be used for the 5G-advanced rollout is the US is in the 3.7-3.98 GHz range. Whereas altimeters operate in the 4.2-4.4 GHz range. Is there any genuine reason to worry about possible interference between these sub-bands, despite over 200 MHz separation between them? What kind of scenarios - like wireless channel conditions, oscillator frequency drift in the carriers, etc could possible lead to interference despite such a large band separation?

[Explainer: Do 5G telecoms pose a threat to airline safety?](https://www.reuters.com/business/aerospace-defense/do-5g-telecoms-pose-threat-airline-safety-2022-01-18/)

Comment: For context: [The FAA advisory](https://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgSAIB.nsf/dc7bd4f27e5f107486257221005f069d/27ffcbb45e6157e9862587810044ad19/$FILE/AIR-21-18.pdf). Please base your question on that; it's where all this excitement comes from.

Comment: My limited understanding is that some airplanes are equipped that bandpass filters that cannot reject enough of the 5G OOB energy. IMO, those filters should be upgraded, but the airlines are trying to avoid paying for it.

Comment: Possible relates/duplicates: [5G and Radar Altimeter Interference - Am I Taking Crazy Pills?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/607266/5g-and-radar-altimeter-interference-am-i-taking-crazy-pills) & [Which radar altimeters are susceptible to 5G C-band altimeter interference?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/91091/which-radar-altimeters-are-susceptible-to-5g-c-band-altimeter-interference)